# Read and print from text file in Java

Tags: java

So I'm using Netbeans to write a simple program, however I've run into a problem printing a txt file.

The code I've written is below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null);

{System.out.println(line);}
```

but when I run the program all it displays is "null", no errors.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There is a `;` after your while statemement. Try removing that.

What you program (in its current form) does is:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
}

System.out.println(line);
```

The last returned value of `in.readLine()` will be `null`, after that it simply prints `null`.

Answer (score 4):

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null);
```

Remove the semicolon. Your code should be

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon `;` at the end of your while statement:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null);
```

which will limit the while loop only to this line and the following block is a normal code block and not part of while loop.

Remove the semicolon to make the following code block `{}` as part of your while loop

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolon

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon on

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null);
```